# LDAP C++ why is ldap_result always busy?

Tags: c++, ldap, openldap

I tried copying this example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/817-6707/search.html
I am trying to get the DN to bind to a user.  But when searching ldap_result always says that the server is busy.  Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?

```
LDAP *ld = NULL;
int iDebug = session.ini["ldap_debug_level"].Int32();
string sHostIP = session.ini["ldap_host"];
string sPort   = session.ini["ldap_port"];
string sURL    = sHostIP+":"+sPort;
int iErr;
iErr = ldap_initialize( &ld, sURL.c_str() );
if( iErr != LDAP_SUCCESS )
{
    ldap_unbind(ld);
    return false;

}

int iVersion = LDAP_VERSION3;
if( ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &iVersion ) != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS )
{
    ldap_unbind(ld);
    return false;

}

string sLDAPPW = session.ini["ldap_server_pw"];
struct berval pServerPassword = { 0, NULL };
pServerPassword.bv_val = ber_strdup( &sLDAPPW[0] );
pServerPassword.bv_len = strlen( pServerPassword.bv_val );

//mysterious code required to prevent crashing
int nsctrls = 0;
LDAPControl c;
c.ldctl_oid = LDAP_CONTROL_PASSWORDPOLICYREQUEST;
c.ldctl_value.bv_val = NULL;
c.ldctl_value.bv_len = 0;
c.ldctl_iscritical = 0;
LDAPControl sctrl[3];
sctrl[nsctrls] = c;
LDAPControl *sctrls[4];
sctrls[nsctrls] = &sctrl[nsctrls];
sctrls[++nsctrls] = NULL;
LDAPControl **sctrlsp = NULL;
if ( nsctrls )
{
    sctrlsp = sctrls;
}

string sBindDN = session.ini["ldap_bind_dn"];
ber_int_t iMsgid;
iErr = ldap_sasl_bind( ld, sBindDN.c_str(), LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, &pServerPassword, sctrlsp, NULL, &iMsgid );
ber_memfree( pServerPassword.bv_val );
if( iErr != LDAP_SUCCESS )
{
    ldap_unbind(ld);
    return false;

}

string sBaseDN  = session.ini["ldap_base_dn"];
string sFilters = "(uid="+sUserName+")";
LDAPMessage *res;
iErr = ldap_search_ext(ld,                     // LDAP            * ld
                        &sBaseDN[0],           // char            * base
                        LDAP_SCOPE_SUBORDINATE,// int               scope
                        &sFilters[0],          // char            * filter
                        NULL,                  // char            * attrs[]
                        0,                     // int               attrsonly
                        NULL,                  // LDAPControl    ** serverctrls
                        NULL,                  // LDAPControl    ** clientctrls
                        NULL,                  //struct timeval *timeoutp
                        LDAP_NO_LIMIT,         //int sizelimit
                        &iMsgid                //ber_int_t iMsgid
);
if (iErr != LDAP_SUCCESS)
{
    ldap_unbind(ld);
    return false;
}

struct timeval zerotime;
zerotime.tv_sec = zerotime.tv_usec = 0L;
int i, parse_rc, finished = 0, num_entries = 0, num_refs = 0; 
char *a, *dn, *matched_msg = NULL, *error_msg = NULL;
BerElement *ber;
char **vals, **referrals;
LDAPControl **serverctrls;
while ( !finished )
{
    iErr = ldap_result( ld, iMsgid, LDAP_MSG_ONE, &zerotime, &res );
    switch ( iErr )
    {
        case -1:
            Log(1, "BasicAuthenticate: error in ldap_result:{}", ldap_err2string(iErr));
            ldap_unbind(ld);
            return false;
            break;
        case 0:
            // The timeout period specified by zerotime was exceeded keep polling
            Log(1, "BasicAuthenticate: server busy: keep polling");
            sleep(1);
            break;
        case LDAP_RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
            num_entries++;
            
            //Get and print the DN of the entry.
            if (( dn = ldap_get_dn( ld, res )) != NULL )
            {
                Log (1, "ldap_get_dn: {}", dn );
                ldap_memfree( dn );
            }
            
            for ( a = ldap_first_attribute( ld, res, &ber ); a != NULL; a = ldap_next_attribute( ld, res, ber ) )
            {
                // Get and print all values for each attribute.
                if (( vals = ldap_get_values( ld, res, a )) != NULL )
                {
                    for ( i = 0; vals[ i ] != NULL; i++ )
                    {
                        Log (1, "ldap_get_values: {}:{}", a, vals[ i ] );
                    }
                    ldap_value_free( vals );
                }
                ldap_memfree( a );
            }
            if ( ber != NULL )
            {
                ber_free( ber, 0 );
            }
            ldap_msgfree( res );
            break; 
        case LDAP_RES_SEARCH_REFERENCE:
            num_refs++;
            parse_rc = ldap_parse_reference( ld, res, &referrals, NULL, 1 );
            if ( parse_rc != LDAP_SUCCESS )
            {
                ldap_unbind(ld);
                return false;
            }

            if ( referrals != NULL )
            {
                for ( i = 0; referrals[ i ] != NULL; i++ )
                {
                    Log(1, "BasicAuthenticate: Search reference:{}", referrals[ i ]);
                }
                ldap_value_free( referrals );
            }

            break;
        case LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT:
            finished = 1;
            parse_rc = ldap_parse_result( ld, res, &iErr, &matched_msg, &error_msg, NULL, &serverctrls, 1 );
            if ( parse_rc != LDAP_SUCCESS )
            {
                kDebugLog(1, "BasicAuthenticate: error in ldap_parse_result:{}", ldap_err2string(parse_rc));
                ldap_unbind(ld);
                return false;
            }
            
            break;
        default:
            break; 
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
 BasicAuthenticate: server busy keep polling
 BasicAuthenticate: error in ldap_parse_result:Server is busy
```

Am I missing a line of code so the server won't be busy?  Is there some sort of incompatibility with the methods I'm using?

Comment: You are specifying a 0ms timeout on `ldap_result()`, so you are just polling it for its current status in a tight loop. Don't treat that as an error condition.  Otherwise, give it an actual non-zero timeout, and then fail if the timeout is actually exceeded.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is probably a better setup than the code I used.  But if I change the timeout to a ridiculous 2 second timeout, then within less than a second the server sends back: error in ldap_parse_result:Server is busy

Comment: I also want to note that I can search the server with ldapserver, so there has to be something wrong with my code instead of my configuration data.

Comment: I would rather look on the firewall side, maybe the return port is blocked.

Comment: @BenoîtBottemanne That is a good suggestion, but in this case, I can reach the server using the ldapsearch app.  So it isn't a firewall issue.  One of my co-workers noticed that the c++ code says that it bound successfully even if we pass it the wrong password, so the error might be at the bind stage.